# Could not find a part of the path appharbor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, appharbor

In my ASP.NET MVC application in which a user can upload file, I'm getting an error. On my local machine it is working fine, but when I deploy it on Appharbor, I am getting thios error:

```
 "Could not find a part of the path "
 'D:\websites\47\d82f8\17989\0x0001\_PublishedWebsites\MyApp\Upload\seeker.pdf
```

I googled around it about and found some possible solutions
like enabling file access in Appharbor, or making sure the directory exists before uploading, but my problem is still there.

EDIT:

```
 qualification.ResumePath = "~/Resumes/" +username + model.Resume.FileName;
 model.Resume.SaveAs(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(qualification.ResumePath));
```

Comment: Why don't you provide some of your code?

Comment: How are you sure the "Resumes" directory exists on the server?

Comment: I uploaded a dummy file to make sure that directory exits.And also, it is working fine on my system

Comment: Well, "your" system is not the server. The message is pretty clear: "there is no such directory". So, check on that first. (Try to get DirectoryInfo, for instance on that path).

Comment: When I changed it to App_Data, it works fine.I did not get where is the problem

Comment: Well, that means either a) App_Data exists, but "Resumes" -- does not; or b) appharbor has setup Read/Write access rights to the first folder, but not to the second one (for the application).